# What is the alternative to QTimer?

Tags: qt, qtimer

The slot function [QTimer::start](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#start) have a interval of millisecond:

> Starts or restarts the timer with a timeout interval of msec milliseconds.

But *msec* is a `int`  type and couldn't take a long interval. What is a alternative to `QTimer` which could take a long interval ?

Comment: How long an interval do you need?  Typically `int` will be a 32 bit integer and can represent approx 2 billion milliseconds -- that's over 20 days.

Comment: @G.M. I need a one-year period.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use something like an hourly timer connected to a function or lambda that checks the current timepoint against a target...

```
/*
 * We want to trigger some event one year from now.
 */
auto endpoint = QDateTime::now().addYears(1);
QTimer hourly_timer;
QObject::connect(&hourly_timer, &QTimer::timeout,
                 [endpoint]()
                   {
                     if (QDateTime::now() >= endpoint) {

                       /*
                        * Target time reached.  Do whatever...
                        */
                     }
                   });
hourly_timer.start(3600 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it look like a really bad code. The [boost.asio.Timer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1.html) do the exactly what i want. But boost.asio.Timer need a another event loop which i somehow don't like it.

Comment: Can I ask what's 'really bad' about it?  Timeout code updating on a timer tick (whether it be hourly. on the second or whatever) is fairly standard stuff.  Also, a timeout of 1 year seems odd/optimistic.  Does the platform it's running on really have an expected uptime that long?  Even high availability systems can have a few seconds downtime over the course of a year.

Comment: @GM, My program which implement a scheduler with QTimer, could be very complicated with the way you suggest to me.

Comment: Okay that's fair enough but... it does make this an xy-problem to a certain extent.  You might want to edit your question to clarify the real problem you're trying to solve -- that of a scheduler.